# Class to Application Communication?

Tags: java, android

I am currently attempting to make a simple app.
I currently have my current programs in an activity class, but now I am attempting to move a part of it into an Application class so that all the other classes can reach the resource without having to go through Intents.

However, I still need to pass information between the two classes, specifically permissions. (That is, both ways - both from and to Application classes)

I have searched for some ways to pass information between two activity classes, but I cannot find ways to communicate between activity-application classes.

Is there any way to go about doing so? Or can I simply use Intents in some way to handle it?

Comment: create static variables in your Application class , set them from your activity. fetch from the activity you want again. You won't need to putExtra for it.
**But be ensure that this wont be the convienient code.**

Comment: Also realize that what you described means that an Activity will have a direct link to an application (and thus never allow for Garbage Collection, until both are destroyed). This usually leads to a lot of memory leakage.

Comment: Okay. I think I'll just make another Class and simply handle the things from there. Cheers for all the help!